# What to do when question can't be repaired with edits?

Tags: discussion, support, bug, questions, editing

Due to a bug, all "zero width non-breaking space" characters were removed from my puzzle when I edited the tag. I tried to edit them back in, but the page keeps deleting them. Since that completely breaks the puzzle, I copied it into an answer and linked that in the question. Not really a nice way to do it, but the only way

But then a mod came along and deleted the answer. So I resubmitted it with a note like "don't delete, that breaks the puzzle", but it was deleted again. Then I resubmitted it again, this time explaining in as much detail as I could why that post should never ever ever be deleted, but, you guessed it, it was deleted.

<s>At this point I don't know what to do. I already asked in chat, but I don't get an answer there. I now have a puzzle with 6 upvotes and a partial solution with 4 upvotes, but it's completely broken and nobody can continue puzzling.</s>

In chat, I compared this with putting a book back into the shelf, but onto a bomb detonation button: Sure, you tidied up your room, but now the house is destroyed. Not really a useful thing to do.

So, may I ask here for the post to stay, please? I don't know anymore how else I can express it, but that post HAS TO stay there.

So what should be done in such a situation? I can't wait for the bug to be fixed, because that can take months (since it's usually not that critical of a bug). I can't just submit a new question, because the upvotes, stars, comments and answers aren't transferred there, also it would likely be closed as a duplicate. I apparently aren't allowed to post it as an answer and link it. A comment doesn't preserve the formatting properly either. So what's left?

Here's a link to the question: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/70497/40546

---

**Update**: I got an answer in chat to my formatting problem. I was told to try a rollback. That actually worked and the puzzle is fixed again. But now the tag is wrong again, of course. I edited this question from "stop deleting my post" to "what to do when I can't repair it with edits", because it's still a valid question, it just isn't as urgent for me anymore.

Answer (score 4):

I feel for you.  You spent the time to design a tricky puzzle, and now the website is not cooperating with you.  It must be frustrating.

That being said, this site has policies and guidelines about how and when to post, and what content is acceptable.  Your solution of putting your question into an answer violates some of those, so it was rightly deleted.

We love to have new and original puzzles contributed on this site, but that doesn't mean that every puzzle is appropriate for this site.  If your puzzle is such that it can't effectively be posted as a question, then perhaps this site is not the best place for it.  You might want to look at posting it elsewhere, or starting your own website and placing it there.

Note that on StackExchange sites, anyone can edit a question, so even if you are careful to post it exactly as you want it right off the bat, it could be broken later by some other well-meaning edit.  This makes this particular puzzle format unsuitable for this site.

Thanks for your willingness to post, and for posting this meta question to help try to sort things out.  I look forward to further contributions from you in the future.